# Combine/group/merge partially the list of lists by equal first field, joining second field in string and writing in other fields same data

Tags: python, algorithm, list, grouping

Example, I have list, I can sort it by first 2 fields, that's ok:

```
import operator
list = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['1', '5', '6'],
    ['2', '8', '9', '8', '17'],
    ['2', '3', '5', '3'],
    ['1', '14', '89', '34', '15'],
]
sorted_list = sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))
```

getting:

```
['1', '14', '89', '34', '15']
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '5', '6']
['2', '3', '5', '3']
['2', '8', '9', '8', '17']
```

So, what I need - is to combine those lists by 1st field, in first step it would be '1' from [0][0], [0][1], [0][2], then I join second field with something like comma: "14:2:5" and I don't care, which part of those 3 list I append then, so, after '|'  it can be any of:

```
['1', '14:2:5',| '89', '34', '15']
['1', '14:2:5',| '3']
['1', '14:2:5',| '6']
```

(in most cases data after '|' will match for first field)

In the end, I want something like:

```
['1', '14:2:5', '89', '34', '15']
['2', '3:8', '5', '3']
```

I'm currently into some sort of for loop and getting IndexError all the way :-(
I feel it should be much easier pythonic way.
Don't get yet how to find this algorithm and how it called. Something like list of lists reduce-map-shrink-normalization elements, appending another by element values?

---

Thanks a lot for helping, things in python still surprise me, how cool it could be done, in the end from all answers, for python 3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import operator
import itertools
from natsort import humansorted

list_to_sort = [
    ['1', 'A', '3'],
    ['1', '5', '6'],
    ['1', '1', '10', '11', '12'],
    ['t', 'S', '7', '0asdf'],
    ['2', '8', '9', '8', '17'],
    ['2', '705', '5', '3'],
    ['2', 'checks', 'df', '1'],
    ['1', '14', '89', '34', '15'],
]

sorted_list = humansorted(list_to_sort, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))
grouped = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x[0])]
out = [[gg[0][0], ':'.join([g[1] for g in gg])] + gg[0][2:] for gg in grouped]

for elem in out:
    print(elem)
```

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of this, but by using simple `operator.itemgetter(0, 1))` you're comparing those items lexicographically not by their actual numeral value.

Comment: Yep, also noticed this, cause in this case '14' stands before '2' in sorted list, in this current case I'm ok with it, cause it actually list of strings. Also found library called [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) and it do those sorting in more 'human way'.

Also found out, that I should not name list with 'list' identifier, cause it built in word :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've sorted your list so that your first-field groups are contiguous, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do the heavy lifting:

```
>>> grouped = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted_list, key=lambda x: x[0])]
>>> grouped
[[['1', '14', '89', '34', '15'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '5', '6']], [['2', '3', '5', '3'], ['2', '8', '9', '8', '17']]]
>>> out = [[gg[0][0], ':'.join([g[1] for g in gg])] + gg[0][2:] for gg in grouped]
>>> out
[['1', '14:2:5', '89', '34', '15'], ['2', '3:8', '5', '3']]
```

Comment: Wow, I need to go and read all about itertools right NOW! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to preserve the sublist with common first item then use a list comprehension with `zip` and `join` to create the desire result:

```
>>> d={}
>>> 
>>> for i,*j in sorted_list:
...    d.setdefault(i,[]).append(iter(j))
... 

>>> [[i,':'.join(next(zip(*j)))]+next(j)[1:] for i,j in d.items()]
[['1', '14:2:5', '89', '34', '15'], ['2', '3:8', '5', '3']]
```

But note that this code have been written in python 3. if you are in python 2 you can use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` and for creating the dictionary you can do :

```
>>> for i in sorted_list:
...    d.setdefault(i[0],[]).append(iter(i[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a pair of functions as shown below. The first one, named `grouper`, is a generator function which are often useful when there's a need to produce intermediate results from a process requires non-trivial amount of initialization and/or housekeeping to be done before multiple intermediate results are returned.

As @Ashwini Chaudhary pointed out in a comment, you were sorting the fields lexicographically, not numerically, in your code, so that issue was also corrected.

```
import operator

def grouper(a_list):
    if a_list:
        sorted_list = sorted(a_list,
                             key=lambda e, get_items=operator.itemgetter(0, 1):
                                map(int, get_items(e)))
        g = [sorted_list[0]]
        for x in sorted_list[1:]:
            if x[0] == g[-1][0]:
                g.append(x)
            else:
                yield g
                g = [x]
        yield g

def combiner(a_list):
    return [[g[0][0], ':'.join(e[1] for e in g)] + g[0][2:]
                for g in grouper(a_list)]

a_list = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['1', '1', '10', '11', '12'],  # element added to test sorting
    ['1', '5', '6'],
    ['2', '8', '9', '8', '17'],
    ['2', '3', '5', '3'],
    ['1', '14', '89', '34', '15'],
]

print(combiner(a_list))
```

Output:

```
[['1', '1:2:5:14', '10', '11', '12'], ['2', '3:8', '5', '3']]
```